# Question regarding Inequation with multivariable functions

Tags: inequality, multivalued-functions

In order to simplify the notation consider: $$ x=[x_1,x_2,...x_n] $$

Consider the following inequation:

$$ s(x)(u(x)+A(x))<0 $$

My goal is to choose the function u(x) such that the inequation holds.
s(x) and A(x) are known.

For instance: 
if s>0:
 $$u(x)+A(x)<0 $$
if s<0:
$$ u(x)+A(x)>0 $$

This problem seems quite easy to solve.

if s>0:
 $$u(x)<-A(x) $$

and if s<0:
$$u(x)>-A(x) $$

However, the textbook solution is quite different and I would like to know why:

Here is the solution:

if s>0
$$u(x)<-\begin{vmatrix}
A(x)
\end{vmatrix} $$

if s<0
$$u(x)>\begin{vmatrix}
A(x)
\end{vmatrix} $$

Answer (score 1):

When $s(x)\ne 0$, there is a lot of freedom to choose the function $u$. Both choices are correct, but your is done in a most general framework, which also shows that the textbook choice is correct.